# Exclude last occurance of duplicate nodes. Duplicates nodes are nodes with multiple attributes with same values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have been trying to write an XPath/XSLT for my problem of detecting and eliminating duplicate nodes. In my case, duplicate nodes are nodes with multiple attributes with same values. The way I want to eliminate duplicate is by excluding the last occurrence of the duplicate node. Please advice if there is any other method.

Pls Note: Duplicate nodes = Nodes with same values of operator1, operator2 and operator3 attributes.

XML:

```
<data id = "root">
  <record id="1" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="2" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="3" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="4" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="5" operator1='xxx' operator2='lkj' operator3='tyu'/>
  <record id="6" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="7" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="8" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="9" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="10" operator1='rrr' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
</data>
```

Output I need:

```
<data id = "root">
  <record id="1" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="2" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="3" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="4" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="6" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
  <record id="7" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
</data>
```

I closest I have come is with this Xpath, but it doesn't work exactly.

```
"//record[(./@operator1 = following-sibling::record/@operator1) and (./@operator2 = following-sibling::record/@operator2) and (./@operator3 = following-sibling::record/@operator3)]".
```

I have searched the whole internet but without any luck. Any help is really really appreciated. Thanks alot.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a correct explanation of what "elimination of duplicates" means and for a short and efficient solution. :)

Comment: Just one more question. How do I parameterize this xslt to pass attribute names at runtime? I mean, I want to pass @operator1, @operator2, @operator3 using <xsl:param>. I tried <xsl:param name="attribute1"></xsl:param> and replace @operator1 inside concat() as concat($attribute1,'***',...). I am passing '@operator1' as value to the parameter 'attribute1'. But it doen't work. Setting the parameters fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been trying to write an
>   XPath/XSLT for my problem of detecting
>   and eliminating duplicate nodes. In my
>   case, duplicate nodes are nodes with
>   multiple attributes with same values.
>   The way I want to eliminate duplicate
>   is by excluding the last occurrence of
>   the duplicate node. Please advice if
>   there is any other method.
>
> Pls Note: Duplicate nodes = Nodes with
>   same values of operator1, operator2
>   and operator3 attributes.

**This is a conflicting definition of duplicate nodes elimination**.

You are *not* eliminating duplicate nodes by just removing the last of a sequence of duplicates. Your desired result:

```
<data id = "root">
    <record id="1" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="2" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="3" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="4" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="6" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="7" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
</data>
```

still contains duplicates such as `record`s with id (1, 4, and 6) and (2, 3, and 7)

**Proper duplicates elimination, also called *deduplication*, requires to leave only one item from all duplicate items**. This is traditionally accomplished in XSLT 1.0 by using the Muenchian method for grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kRecByAtts" match="record"
  use="concat(@operator1,'***',
              @operator2,'***',
              @operator3)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "record
      [not(generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kRecByAtts',
                       concat(@operator1,'***',
                              @operator2,'***',
                              @operator3)
                       )[1]
                   )
            )
       ]
  "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data id = "root">
    <record id="1" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="2" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="3" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="4" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="6" operator1='xxx' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
    <record id="7" operator1='abc' operator2='yyy' operator3='zzz'/>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<data id="root">
   <record id="1" operator1="xxx" operator2="yyy" operator3="zzz"/>
   <record id="2" operator1="abc" operator2="yyy" operator3="zzz"/>
</data>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks alot. Exactly what I needed. I will add points later when I get 15 points to vote up an answer.

Comment: @Dimitre: Just one more question. How do I parameterize this xslt to pass attribute names at runtime? I mean, I want to pass @operator1, @operator2, @operator3 using <xsl:param>. I tried <xsl:param name="attribute1"></xsl:param> and replace @operator1 inside concat() as concat($attribute1,'***',...). I am passing '@operator1' as value to the parameter 'attribute1'. But it doen't work. Setting the parameters fails.

Comment: @JayRaj: With a param you must have: `@*[name()=$attribute1]`

Comment: @Dimitre: Sorry to bug you again. Your last suggested method, @*[name()=$attribute1] is not working somehow.                                                            The error is, ....Error instantiating native XSLT processor: Variables may not be used within this expression.

concat(@*[name()=-->$attribute1<--],'***').

Comment: @JayRaj: Unfortunately, in XSLT 1.0 an `<xsl:key>` must not contain a variable/parameter reference. So, my suggestion will work in XSLT 2.0 only. It seems that the Muenchian method cannot be used with external parameters. In this case another, very inefficient (O(N^2))for large number of records algorithm can still be used. Can you, please, ask this as a new question and signal to me.

Comment: @Dimitre: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613267/how-to-eliminate-duplicate-nodes-bases-on-values-of-multiple-attributes-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that eliminates the last of duplicate 'record' elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="record" 
           use="concat(@operator1, '|', @operator2, '|', @operator3)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record[generate-id() 
                              = 
                              generate-id(key('k1', 
                                              concat(@operator1, '|', 
                                                     @operator2, '|', 
                                                     @operator3))[last()])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```